Not able to create a repo using template repo GIthub API
I have generated a personal access token and configured Single Sign-On (SSO), providing full authorization to the token. The issue I'm facing is that while I can successfully create GitHub repositories, retrieve repository details, and list repositories using the same token, I am unable to create a repository from a template repository. I wrote a Python script to accomplish this, but I am encountering a 404 error. Below is the dummy code I used for this task:
import requests
import json

# Replace with your actual access token and template repository details
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'your_github_token'  # Your GitHub token
ORG_NAME = 'DummyWorld'               # Organization name
TEMPLATE_OWNER = 'DummyOwner'         # Owner of the template repository
TEMPLATE_REPO = 'DummyTemplateRepo'   # Name of the template repository
NEW_REPO_OWNER = 'DummyWorld'         # Owner of the new repository (organization)
NEW_REPO_NAME = 'DummyWorld-TestRepo' # Name of the new repository
DESCRIPTION = 'This is a test repository created from a template.'  # Description for the new repository
INCLUDE_ALL_BRANCHES = False          # Include all branches from the template
PRIVATE = True                        # Set to True for a private repository

# GitHub API endpoint to generate a new repository from a template
url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{TEMPLATE_OWNER}/{TEMPLATE_REPO}/generate'

# Headers for the request
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}',
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
}

# Data for the request
data = {
    'owner': NEW_REPO_OWNER,
    'name': NEW_REPO_NAME,
    'description': DESCRIPTION,
    'include_all_branches': INCLUDE_ALL_BRANCHES,
    'private': PRIVATE,
}

# Make the POST request to generate the repository
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 201:
    print("\nRepository created successfully:")
    created_repo_info = response.json()
    print("-" * 50)
    print(f"Repository Name: {created_repo_info['name']}")
    print(f"Full Name: {created_repo_info['full_name']}")
    print(f"Description: {created_repo_info['description']}")
    print(f"Private: {created_repo_info['private']}")
    print("-" * 50)
else:
    print(f"\nFailed to create repository: {response.status_code}")
    print("Error Response:")
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))  # Pretty print the error response
    enter code here

error code:
Failed to create repository: 404
Error Response:
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest",
    "status": "404"
}


The above issue has been solved by adding "organisation name" as template owner and NEW_REPO_OWNER
TEMPLATE_OWNER = 'DummyOwner'         # Owner of the template repository
TEMPLATE_REPO = 'DummyTemplateRepo'   # Name of the template repository
NEW_REPO_OWNER = 'DummyOwner'
